# Merging two tables using criteria with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to resolve something with just one linq sentence, and I dont know if is possible do this.
I have one table named PRICES, with this fields:

```
 pkey: int
 region: int?
 product_type: int
 product_size: int
 price: double
 desc: string
```

The unique key is: product_type + product_size

I want to do a query that returns all rows WHERE region == 17
(this is my first set of rows)
AND want to add all rows where region is null
(this is my second set of rows)
BUT
 if there are rows with the same product_type and product_size in both sets, i want in the final result just the row of the first set.

Example:

```
pkey | region | product_type | product_size | price | desc

 1,    null,    20,            7,             2.70,   salad1    
 2,    null,    20,            3,             2.50,   salad7    
 3,    17,      20,            7,             1.90,   saladspecial    
 4,    17,      20,            5,             2.20,   other
```

I want a linq query that returns this:

```
 2,    null,    20,            3,             2.50,   salad7    
 3,    17,      20,            7,             1.90,   saladspecial    
 4,    17,      20,            5,             2.20,   other
```

(note that row with pkey 1 is discarded because the row with pkey 3 has the same product_type and product_size)

```
var query1 = from p in PRICES where p.region == 17    
             select p;

var query2 = from p in PRICES where p.region is null     
             select p;
```

Questions:

1. How to join query1 and query2 to obtain the expected output?
2. It can be done with just 1 query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query selects only prices with region `17` or `null`, groups them by unique key `{ p.product_type, p.product_size }`. Then it checks whether group contain at least one price with region `17`. If yes, then we select all prices of this region from group (and skipping prices with `null` region). Otherwise we return whole group (it has null regions only):

```
var query = from p in PRICES.Where(x => x.region == 17 || x.region == null)
            group p by new { p.product_type, p.product_size } into g
            from pp in g.Any(x => x.region == 17) ? 
                       g.Where(x => x.region == 17) : g
            select pp;
```

Input:

```
1 null 20 7 2.7 salad1       // goes to group {20,7} with region 17 price
2 null 20 3 2.5 salad7       // goes to group {20,3} without region 17 prices
3   17 20 7 1.9 saladspecial // goes to group {20,7}
4   17 20 5 2.2 other        // goes to group {20,5}
```

Output:

```
2 null 20 3 2.5 salad7 
3   17 20 7 1.9 saladspecial
4   17 20 5 2.2 other
```

**EDIT** Query above works fine with objects in memory (i.e. LINQ to Objects) but LINQ to Entitis is not that powerful - it does not support nested queries. So, for Entity Framework you will need two queries - one to fetch prices with `null` region, which does not have region `17` prices in the group, and second - prices from region `17`:

```
var pricesWithoutRegion = 
            db.PRICES.Where(p => p.region == 17 || p.region == null)
              .GroupBy(p => new { p.product_type, p.product_size })
              .Where(g => !g.Any(p => p.region == 17))
              .SelectMany(g => g);

var query = db.PRICES.Where(p => p.region == 17).Concat(pricesWithoutRegion);
```

Actually EF executes both sub-queries in one `UNION` query to server. Following SQL will be generated (I removed *desc* and *price* columns to fit screen):

```
SELECT [UnionAll1].[pkey] AS [C1], 
       [UnionAll1].[region] AS [C2], 
       [UnionAll1].[product_type] AS [C3], 
       [UnionAll1].[product_size] AS [C4]
FROM (SELECT [Extent1].[pkey] AS [pkey], 
             [Extent1].[region] AS [region], 
             [Extent1].[product_type] AS [product_type], 
             [Extent1].[product_size] AS [product_size]
      FROM [dbo].[Prices] AS [Extent1] WHERE 17 = [Extent1].[region]
UNION ALL
   SELECT [Extent4].[pkey] AS [pkey], 
          [Extent4].[region] AS [region], 
          [Extent4].[product_type] AS [product_type], 
          [Extent4].[product_size] AS [product_size]
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Extent2].[product_type] AS [product_type], 
                         [Extent2].[product_size] AS [product_size]
         FROM [dbo].[Prices] AS [Extent2]
         WHERE ([Extent2].[region] = 17 OR [Extent2].[region] IS NULL) AND 
               (NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[Prices] AS [Extent3]
                 WHERE ([Extent3].[region] = 17 OR [Extent3].[region] IS NULL)
                       AND ([Extent2].[product_type] = [Extent3].[product_type])
                       AND ([Extent2].[product_size] = [Extent3].[product_size])
                       AND (17 = [Extent3].[region])
                 ))) AS [Distinct1]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Prices] AS [Extent4] 
       ON ([Extent4].[region] = 17 OR [Extent4].[region] IS NULL)
          AND ([Distinct1].[product_type] = [Extent4].[product_type])
          AND ([Distinct1].[product_size] = [Extent4].[product_size]))
   AS [UnionAll1]
```

BTW it's surprise to me that `GroupBy` was translated into inner join with conditions.

Comment: I having an exception with your query: "A valid ResultType could not be inferred from the ResultTypes of the specified 'Then' expressions." Why is this happening?

Comment: @DiegoGalo I've tested the query of `lazyberezovsky` and it works OK. The style of `expression` makes this query more concise than the `method` style.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky how do you know the corresponding `SQL query` to the `LINQ query`? Any tool? thanks!

Comment: @KingKing in this case I used SQL Profiler (you can find it in *All Programs > SQL Server > Performance Tools*) also nice option is [Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) you can get it's trial from NuGet

Comment: Great work guys. There is another way to know the SQL query. Just put a breakpoint, and point with your mouse on pricesWithoutRegion, and you will see the IQueryable and the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for 1 query, for 2 queries, we have to repeat something:

```
//for 2 queries
var query = query1.Union(query2.Except(query2.Where(x=>query1.Any(y=>x.product_type==y.product_type&&x.product_size==y.product_size))))
                  .OrderBy(x=>x.pkey);

//for 1 query
//the class/type to make the group key
public class GroupKey
{
        public int ProductType { get; set; }
        public int ProductSize { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            GroupKey gk = obj as GroupKey;
            return ProductType == gk.ProductType && ProductSize == gk.ProductSize;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ProductSize ^ ProductType;
        }
}
//-------
var query = list.Where(x => x.region == 17 || x.region == null)
                .GroupBy(x => new GroupKey{ProductType = x.product_type, ProductSize = x.product_size })
                .SelectMany<IGrouping<GroupKey,Price>,Price,Price>(x => x.Where(k => x.Count(y => y.region == 17) == 0 || k.region == 17), (x,g) => g)
                .OrderBy(x=>x.pkey);
```

Comment: Nice use of SelectMany clause, your solutions worked very nicely

Comment: Error 42 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TCollection,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TCollection>>, System.Func<TSource,TCollection,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.